# The meaning of a quote

Tags: metaphors

***Censorship is the mother of metaphor***. - Jorge Luis Borges.

My literal understanding doesn't give me the real, implicit meaning of the quote of one of the greatest authors.

Hope for your reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @aparente001: Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means this: When you cannot say what you want directly, because your words will be censored, you can often find a metaphorical way to get your point across.

Comment: And this was very common in South American while the repressive regimes were in power.